# How to deal with Variables in Batch - Removing line from all files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, concatenation

so I have a folder full of json-files who have one line, that I want to remove. Since I am new to batch-scripting, I am facing some problems. This is, what I have so far:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

ren *.json *.old
for %%x in (*.old) do (
    set filename=%%~nx
    set extension=.json
    set finalname=%filename%%extension%
    type %%x | findstr /v string %%x >> %finalname%
    del %%x
)
```

But it all doesnt seem to work. When I echo the %finalname% for example, it's empty, so the concatenation doesnt seem to work. Also what I still need to is, to make sure whitespaces in filenames get handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand with delayed expansion use `!` instead of `%`

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

ren *.json *.old
for %%x in (*.old) do (
    set "filename=%%~nx"
    set "extension=.json"
    set "finalname=!filename!!extension!"
    type "%%x" | findstr /v "string" "%%x" >>"!finalname!"
    del "%%x"
)
```

But ...what you want to achieve with this line:

`type %%x | findstr /v string %%x >> %finalname%`  - (when you use piped content you do not need to point a file) ?

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Not only the ! but also the ""''s were the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: So I think `findstr /v "string" "%%~fx" >> "!filename!"` would be enough (I'd avoid the pipe due to performance reasons)...

Answer (score 1):

As npocmaka points, you can solve the problem in your code with correct delayed expansion syntax in the variable references, or you can directly remove the variables:

```dos
ren *.json *.old
for %%x in (*.old) do (
    type "%%x" | findstr /v /c:"string" > "%%~nx.json"
    del "%%x"
)
```

Instead of storing the values you need inside variables, just use the values.